# PANDAS: Combining data frames with IDs in common

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I have two dataframes, df1 and df2, each containing different information and of different length, but with a column 'DAY' in common, though not always with the same value.  For context, one data frame contains a record of precipitation, the other contains a record of flood events and their size. I would like to combine them so that I can easily compare what precipitation conditions are associated with flood events. df1 (precipitation) looks like this:

```
D   M   Y       DAY     Tpcp    MaxInt
30  9   2010    5553    20.8    2.2
1   10  2010    5554    14      1.8
2   10  2010    5555    61.8    1.8
3   10  2010    5556    30      1.2
4   10  2010    5557    68.4    1
5   10  2010    5558    10.2    1
6   10  2010    5559    82.8    2.2
7   10  2010    5560    54.6    2.2
10  10  2010    5563    11.4    1.8
```

df2 (floods) looks like this:

```
D   M   Y       DAY     Size
12  5   2009    5047    2
3   9   2009    5161    2
13  4   2010    5383    3
14  4   2010    5384    3
16  7   2010    5477    2
4   10  2010    5557    3
6   10  2010    5559    3
30  4   2011    5765    2
22  5   2011    5787    2
27  5   2011    5792    2
9   11  2011    5958    2
```

Floods do not occur on all days with rain, so what I am aiming for looks like this, with zeros for when no event occurs:

```
D   M   Y       DAY     Tpcp    MaxInt   FldSz
30  9   2010    5553    20.8    2.2      0
1   10  2010    5554    14      1.8      0
2   10  2010    5555    61.8    1.8      0
3   10  2010    5556    30      1.2      0
4   10  2010    5557    68.4    1        3      
5   10  2010    5558    10.2    1        3
6   10  2010    5559    82.8    2.2      0
7   10  2010    5560    54.6    2.2      0
10  10  2010    5563    11.4    1.8      0
```

Again, I think the easiest way is to merge/combine according to 'DAY'. Perhaps this is a really obvious task, apologies if so (I am new to this), but I could not find any answers that I thought suited the problem and wondered whether there may be some suggestions out there... thanks in advance for any thoughts and contributions :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if this solve what you mean:

```
df = df1.merge(df2, on=['D', 'M', 'Y', 'DAY'], how='left')
df['FldSz'] = df['Size'].fillna(0)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this one gets it closest to the desired state, I just need to then remove one column. Thank you all for your input and for coming back so fast! Really appreciate it :)

Comment: Actually, I have double checked this and there is one bit missing, which perhaps I hadn't described in the post. Do you know of any way to include the D M Y DAY values in df2? What I mean by this, is that now I have df3 with the D M Y DAY values of df1 with the Size column added, however, there are days on which flooding has occurred but without rainfall being registered. These flood days have their own D M Y DAY values, but are not included in df3. Do you have any idea as to how I can add these?

Comment: you can choose `how='outer'` so that all keys(DMY DAY) of both data frames will be reserved. If you have any question merging tables, can refer here: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need [pandas.join](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html).

```
res = df1.join(df2.set_index('DAY'), on='DAY')
```

and rename the size column/ fill N/A as 0's.

Answer (score 1):

You're right to use a `merge`, but you want to set `how="outer"` when you perform that merge.

```
df3 = df1.merge(df2[["DAY", "Size"]], how="left")
```

Setting `how="left"` will return all the rows from your left-most table (`df1` in this case) even if there isn't a matching record in `df2`.  For the records where there is no matching record a `NaN` will fill the `df2` columns where there is no record in `df1`.

Comment: thanks for your input here! I failed to mention this in the post, but there are some days on which flooding occurs without rainfall being logged. At this point, I have NAN for the flood size when flooding is not present but rainfall is, but the new df does not show days on which no rainfall occurred but flooding persisted. In other words, I need to included 'DAY' values from both data frames, but in this solution I only have them from df1, which excludes useful information from df2. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: In that case change `how="left"` to `how="outer"` (answer has been updated to show this).  Using an `outer` join will return all values in both `df1` and `df2` with `NaN` values where no match was found.  You can learn a lot more about merging in pandas from [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html) for you to reference, which includes information about all the different merging behaviors you can use.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
data = pd.merge(df1,df2, on=['DAY'], how='outer')
```